# Sudo su issue on ubuntu 14.04 lts: /root/zsh can't not be found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have recently re-installed ubuntu 14.04 lts and I installed my favorite shell (zsh) but I am having an issue now.

When I type, `sudo su` it comes back with an error stating `/root/zsh` can not be found.

I am not sure what I need to do to fix this as this is the first time I have had this error when using this system.

Also when I do, `sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh`

I get

```
PAM_AUTHENTICATION failed
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to boot into runlevel1 or use a live environment to make changes to `/etc/passwd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`su` executes your login shell as indicated in the login database. This is `/root/zsh`, which doesn't exist, so the command `su` fails.

`chsh` only accepts changing the shell of a user who currently has a valid shell (listed in `/etc/shells`). Since `/root/zsh` is not accepted, `chsh` fails. The root user can change anyone's shell, but this test is made after the validity check for the current shell.

However `sudo` itself doesn't care about your login shell (unless you run `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`). So you have plenty of ways to repair your system: `sudo /bin/zsh` gives you a shell, from which you can run `vipw` and correct the entry for root. You can even run `sudo vipw` directly.

I recommend starting a root shell in one terminal and doing the configuration change in another terminal. Don't exit that root shell until you've confirmed that the system is back to a working state by testing that `sudo -i` or `sudo su` works.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you very much! :D